# Performing calculation on multiple columns with the same condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],
                   [-1,3,2],
                   [3,4,5],
                   [-3,4,5]], columns=['A','B','C'])
condition = df['A']>0
df.loc[condition, 'B'] = df['B'] + 1
df.loc[condition, 'C'] = df['C'] * 2
print(df.head())
```

I am performing two different operations on two columns based on the same condition. What is the best way to group these two lines of code into a one liner?

```
df.loc[condition, 'B'] = df['B'] + 1
df.loc[condition, 'C'] = df['C'] * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) by both `Series`, because different operations:

```
df.loc[condition, ['B','C']] = pd.concat([df['B'] + 1, df['C'] * 2], axis=1)
print(df)
   A  B   C
0  1  3   6
1 -1  3   2
2  3  5  10
3 -3  4   5
```

In my opinion 2 rows are more readable:

```
df.loc[condition, 'B'] += 1
df.loc[condition, 'C'] *= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with assign:

```py
df.assign(B = df.B.mask(condition, df.B + 1), 
          C = df.C.mask(condition, df.C * 2))
Out[298]:
   A  B   C
0  1  3   6
1 -1  3   2
2  3  5  10
3 -3  4   5
```